# How to achieve the same appbar-design as Periscope's Android app?

Tags: android

Here is a screenshot of the toolbar. It has three navigation items to the left which looks just like a tab-layout. When you select the third tab, a menu item pops up from right side of the toolbar.

[image: Periscope]

How can i achieve this look? Is this a tablayout inside a toolbar? Or a tablayout and a toolbar next to each other? I've tried some stuff but failed.

Comment: Please, embed the image into the question instead of just linking it. External images makes it harder to get the whole context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use [TabBarView](https://github.com/Mirkoddd/TabBarView). Then, in the `Fragment` you want a `MenuItem` to show (like the last tab in Periscope), add `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` and have the `MenuItem`'s visibility be `app:showAsAction="always"`. [Wally](https://github.com/Musenkishi/wally/blob/master/wally/src/main/java/com/musenkishi/wally/views/TabBarView.java) also uses this UI pattern.